# REST API Random Authentication Failure on Sandbox

Tags: rest-api, sandbox, authentication

I've encountered a problem where a sandbox completely stops allowing me to login.  Nothing changed in the sandbox configuration.  I'm still able to login via the web interface using the exact same credentials, and I can also still login to my other sandboxes.

My setup:

- python
- REST API
- [simple_salesforce](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-salesforce)

This has happened to me twice: once on a development sandbox and again on a full sandbox.  The only way I could recover was to completely delete and re-create the sandbox.

Anyone know what's going on?

**Edit: More Info**

I was trying to login to Salesforce from home this weekend when I couldn't connect.  Now that I'm back in the office, I can connect to the API without any trouble.  I checked, and there are no IP range restrictions on the sandbox; besides, I could still connect via the web interface.

Additionally, I tested the connection to the full sandbox and was successfully able to connect via the API.  This had previously stopped working, and I could not get in even while at work.

Comment: Anything interesting in the login history ?

Comment: techtrekker - Nothing stands out in the log history.  It just says "Invalid Password."

Comment: Do you need to add a security token when working from home? Perhaps your company's IP range is whitelisted as secure?

Comment: Mike Chale - I thought that when logging into a sandbox, the security token has to be an empty string.  I'll test it when I get home.  I'll also try to add my home IP to the whitelist and see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

Looks a trusted IP setting to me.

When you access via API from within your organisation's trusted IP Range the security token is not required. That becomes necessary from outside the IP range.

Try checking Security Controls > Network Access under setup. [More info here.](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_networkaccess.htm)

I hope it helps.